# SQLite Update and Insert stop working when Published in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my first project with web forms and this is the one problem I couldn't solve. The code works when run in debug but not when I publish it to IIS. I set the page to not refresh on postback but I don't know if I need to set a button property different from default.

Thanks

```
protected void Bt_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(GlobalVar.SQLiteConString))
        {
            try
            {

               string sql = "UPDATE WO_GrowLog " +
                    "SET Area = '" + TB_Area.Text + "'," +
                    "CropID = '" + TB_CropID.Text + "'," +
                    "ProductID = '" + DD_Product.Text + "'," +
                    "Container = '" + DD_Container.Text + "'," +
                    "NumContainers = '" + TB_ContainerNum.Text + "'," +
                    "Task = '" + DD_Tasks.Text + "'," +
                    "CompletedDate = '" +TB_CompletionDate.Text + "'," +
                    "AreaType = '" + DD_AreaType.Text + "'," +
                    "AreaDescrip = '" + TB_AreaDis.Text + "'," +
                    "Employee = '" + DD_Employees.Text + "'," +
                    "EstimatedCompletion = '" + TB_EstDate.Text +
                    "' WHERE ID = '" + ViewState["IDs"].ToString() + "';";


                command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("******* Error In Bt_Save_Click(): " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you show the exception when run on IIS? Maybe temporarily disable the catch block, or write to event log or a text file instead.

Comment: Martheen, I just found a post that also suggested disabling the catch block, and that told me the permissions for the database were read-only. That fixed everything is working. Thanks for your comment and sorry I wasted your time on what now seems obvious.

Comment: Glad it worked out well. We've all been there